# Get data from jsonb field array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following schema in PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    raw jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, raw, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, '{ "slides": [{"id": "1", "name": "Test", "finished_at": 1517421628092}, {"id": "2", "name": "Test", "finished_at": 1517421894736}]}', now(), now());
```

I want to get data from `raw['slides']`. I want to have query which return every `raw['slides'] id` and `raw['slides'] finished_at`. So result of a query should look like this:

```
id  finished_at
1 1517421628092
2 1517421894736
```

Here is sqlfiddle to experiment with:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ae504

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unnest the array, then you can access each element:

```
select s.slide ->> 'id' as id,
       s.slide ->> 'finished_at' as finished_at
from survey_results, jsonb_array_elements(raw -> 'slides') as s (slide)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ae504/80

For more details see [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in the manual.